# How to get the files from a specified path in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am copying a set of zli files from a folder to another folder. Now i need to decompress each file in that folder. I am running python using Pycharm from Windows and the folders are in a Linux server. How can i get to the current folder and decompress each file?

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
import ConfigParser, paramiko, shutil, os, glob, zlib

def get_Connection():
    config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
    config.read('config.cfg')
    env.user = config.get('UK_CDN','db.user_name' )
    env.password = config.get('UK_CDN','db.password' )
    host = config.get('UK_CDN','db.ip' )

    with settings(hide('warnings', 'running', 'stdout', 'stderr'), warn_only=True, host_string=host):
    paramiko.util.log_to_file('ENC_Analysis.log')
    files = run('ls -ltr /home/ndsuser/enc/data/dbSchema_1/catalogue_24802')
    run('rm -rf  /usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/*')
    run('cp /home/ndsuser/enc/data/dbSchema_1/catalogue_24802/* /usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/')
    count = run('ls -l /usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/ | wc -l')
    os.chdir('/usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/')
    for file in os.listdir('/usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/'):
        print file
```

If i run this code, i gets the issue as below.

```
  File "C:/Work/Scripts/VOD/ENC.py", line 20, in get_Connection
os.chdir('/usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/')
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:  '/usr/rosh/ENC_Analysis/'
```

I know this issue is due to the fact that system is not able to find a path in the Windows machine. How can i get to the path in a Linux Server from a Windows machine?

Comment: Windows does not have the path `/usr/rosh/XXX` or something. Are you running python through cygwin? Otherwise you'd have to give a correct path with drive specificatons like `c:/users/` etc.

Comment: There is no straight forward way to copy files from remote host using python. You'll probably need to copy the data to your localhost (Winodws) or copy the python program to remote host (Linux) and run it there. I suggest the latter, run the python program on linux server

Comment: @gabhijit.. I clearly mentioned that i am running Python Through Pycharm in WIndows and trying to access Linux Server.

Comment: I am sorry!! my bad!

Comment: @gabhijit... No problem at all :) But do you have any solution for this? I don't want to copy the files from Linux to Windows manually and do it.

Comment: I think for this you just need to add a check that - whether the directory exists. If not create that directory. That should be simple. There's `stat` command for that. before running the `rm` and `cp` commands. I'd start with that.

Answer (score 2):

You can set PyCharm up to automatically copy the python script to a remote server and run it there. The PyCharm documentation for this is at https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html

Since you've already imported paramiko, you could also send all the relevant commands over an ssh session to the linux server, while running the script locally. This seems a bit more awkward, but would still work.

```
sshconnection = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshconnection.connect(hostname, username=..., password=... )
stdin, stdout, stderr = sshconnection.exec_command('ls -ltr /home/...')
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks Simon. Is there any other alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: Your options are, really: 1. run the script on the linux server.  2. Copy the files to the windows server and run the script there. 3. run the script on the windows server and ssh to the linux server to run all the commands.

Comment: @ Simon. The option of adding Add Remote is only in the Professional version. Also i need to use Pycharm only in WIndows due to many other internal project factors. So hence i am trying to get the best solution for this.

Comment: I would still say the simplest option is to copy the script to the linux server and run it there, assuming it doesn't need to be on the windows server for any part of its execution. If it does, then paramiko is likely the best bet.